# Why Spark doesn't redistribute the tasks among executors?

Tags: parallel-processing, apache-spark, emr

I am running a spark job which is 99% finished. The last 1% takes a long time, so I checked the job tracker. As shown in the screenshot, we can see that some executors still have several active tasks while some have 0 task. Why doesn't Spark redistribute the tasks?

Also, for the last 1% job which took a long time, is it mainly due to memory issue, number of executor cores, or ...? Is there a way I can find out why?

Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Moving an active task isn't really supported, you can turn on speculative execution however and Spark will try and launch another copy of the same task on another node if it looks like its going slow.

There are a large number of reasons why the last 1% of tasks can be taking much longer, you might want to look at the distribution of task input or output to see if you perhaps have unbalanced data (the most common reason for stragglers like this).

Answer (score 0):

Just to further expand on @Holden's answer. She is right, the most likely reason is that the RDD you are working on has skewed partitions, that's why you are seeing that last 1% taking infinitely long time. One way to debug this is to check the size of each partition, and if you see a partition much bigger then others, then you have to repartition the data equally.

A very similar issue is answered in detail in [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40981512/spark-cores-tasks-concurrency/41171632#41171632).